# calculate shipping prices based on the weight (js es6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to calculate the price of the shipping costs according to the weight of the article. but when the weight is multiply, my function does not find the weight. Example I have an article which weighs 3 kg, the price of the expenses is 4 € for 3 kg. if I take two products of the same weight (so 8kg) the system returns me undefined because in my table, I have the price for 5kg and 10 kg but not 8 kg yet , it should choose 5kg.

```js
var shippingPrices = [{"price":"1.25","weight":"1.00"},{"price":"4.00","weight":"5.00"},{"price":"6.25","weight":"10.00"}];

window.addEventListener('load',() => {
    let productPrice = document.getElementById('price').value;
    let productWeight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    let quantity = document.querySelector('[name="quantity"]');
    function updatePrice(quantity){
        return Number(quantity) * productPrice
    }
    function updateWeight(quantity){
        return Number(quantity) * productWeight
    }
    function getShippingPrice(weight) {
        return (shippingPrices.find(a => a.weight >= weight) || {}).price;
    }

    if(quantity !== null && quantity !== undefined) {
        let total = updatePrice(quantity.value);
        let totalWeight = updateWeight(quantity.value);
        let totalShipping = getShippingPrice(totalWeight.toFixed(2));

        console.log("total "+total.toFixed(2));
        console.log("poids total "+totalWeight.toFixed(2));
        console.log("prix poids "+totalShipping);
        quantity.addEventListener('change', function () {
            let total = updatePrice(this.value);//Number(this.value) * price
            let totalWeight = updateWeight(this.value);
            let totalShipping = getShippingPrice(totalWeight.toFixed(2));
            console.log("total "+total.toFixed(2));
            console.log("poids total "+totalWeight.toFixed(2));
            console.log("prix poids "+totalShipping);
        });
    }
});
```

Best Regards

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Can you please make it much cleaner?

Comment: Why do you define `price` and `weight` as strings?

Comment: Hi, I can't edit my text.
Is the explanation unclear ?
my getShippingPrice function does not choose the weight if it is not in the json .
So, I'm looking to modify the condition of getShippingPrice but I'm not familiar with find()

Comment: @derpirscher
json from PHP : var shippingPrices = [{"price":"1.25","weight":"1.00"},{"price":"4.00","weight":"5.00"},{"price":"6.25","weight":"10.00"}];

Comment: *"I have an article which weighs 3 kg, [...] if I take two products of the same weight (so 8kg)"*: you lost me. Isn't 3*2=6? Please provide a few examples of input, expected output.

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 var shippingPrices = [
  { price: 1.25, weight: 1.00 },
  { price: 4.00, weight: 5.00 },
  { price: 6.25, weight: 10.00 }
];

    var form = document.getElementById('calculator-form');
    var totalPriceElement = document.getElementById('total-price');
    var shippingCostElement = document.getElementById('shipping-cost');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var productPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').value);
      var productWeight = parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').value);
      var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value);

      var total = productPrice * quantity;
      var totalWeight = productWeight * quantity;
      var totalShipping = getShippingPrice(totalWeight.toFixed(2));

      totalPriceElement.textContent = total.toFixed(2);
      shippingCostElement.textContent = totalShipping;
    });
function getShippingPrice(weight) {
  // Sort the shippingPrices array by weight in descending order
  shippingPrices.sort((a, b) => b.weight - a.weight);

  let closestLowerWeight = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < shippingPrices.length; i++) {
    if (shippingPrices[i].weight <= weight) {
      closestLowerWeight = shippingPrices[i];
      break; // Stop searching when we find a weight less than or equal to the target weight
    }
  }

  if (closestLowerWeight) {
    return closestLowerWeight.price + ' €';
  }

  // If no match is found, you can handle this case, e.g., return a default price
  return "Price not found for this weight";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shipping Cost Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Shipping Cost Calculator</h1>
  <form id="calculator-form">
    <div>
      <label for="price">Product Price:</label>
      <input type="number" id="price" placeholder="Enter product price" step="0.01" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="weight">Product Weight (kg):</label>
      <input type="number" id="weight" placeholder="Enter product weight" step="0.01" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity" min="1" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <div id="results">
    <p>Total Price: <span id="total-price">0.00</span> €</p>
    <p>Total Shipping Cost: <span id="shipping-cost">0.00</span> €</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I adapted your script to mine, but it always returns me the first value of the array.
So the getShippingPrice part but impossible to get the right value

Comment: i have update the getShippingPrice function hope it will help otherwise please give some real world examples about your problem

Comment: `shippingPrices[i].weight <= weight` will do a *string comparison* which will return wrong results ... for instance `"5.00" <= "10.00"` will return `false`

Comment: The only adaption necessary in OP's code is to use numbers instead of strings for all prices and weights ...

Comment: @GeritsAurelien now check

Comment: Do you even try your code once before you post it? For a `weight`of `3` this will return the shipping costs of `1.25` which is for the weight of `1` and below. OP cleary states in his question, that in this case it should return the shipping costs of `4.00` which is for the weight of `5` and below ...

Comment: @Mohammad Akram
I formatted the json correctly for numeric types and it works, thanks